# Getting an error for a missing file on a aem project that is no longer installed

Tags: aem, aem-6

When editing a template I see an 404 error for a file that is supposed to no longer exist in my js console. When I try to open it I see this error:

```
Resource at '/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html' not found: No resource found
Cannot serve request to /conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html in /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp

Request Progress:
      0 TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      3 COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed microseconds>,<timer name>} <optional message>
     10 LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=null
     13 TIMER_START{handleSecurity}
   1613 TIMER_END{1597,handleSecurity} authenticator org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator@6e7c2e44 returns true
   3677 TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
   3865 TIMER_END{186,ResourceResolution} URI=/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html resolves to Resource=NonExistingResource, path=/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html
   3872 LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null'
   3873 TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
   3877 TIMER_START{resolveServlet(/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html)}
   4597 LOG {0}: no servlet found
   4606 TIMER_END{727,resolveServlet(/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html)} Using servlet org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
   4610 TIMER_END{737,ServletResolution} URI=/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html handled by Servlet=org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
   4614 LOG Applying Requestfilters
   4619 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl
   4625 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter
   4629 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
   4632 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter
   4638 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
   4640 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker
   4642 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter
   4752 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
   4768 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.servlets.CoreFormHandlingServlet
   4773 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter
   4778 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
   4780 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter
   4784 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
   4787 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
   4790 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl
   4871 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter
   4873 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter
   4877 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl
   4884 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter
   4887 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler
   4897 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler
   4900 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet
   4902 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
   4909 LOG Applying Componentfilters
   4911 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter
   4913 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.page.PageLockFilter
   4915 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
   4925 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
   4934 TIMER_START{org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet#0}
   4992 TIMER_END{57,org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet#0}
   5011 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter, inner=0, total=0, outer=0
   5013 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter, inner=0, total=1, outer=1
   5014 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.page.PageLockFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5059 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.dtm.reactor.impl.servlets.ClientLibraryFilter, inner=0, total=1, outer=1
   5061 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.dam.webdav.impl.io.DamWebdavRequestFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5062 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5063 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5065 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.dtm.impl.servlets.DTMLibraryCompatibilityFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5066 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5068 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.DamContentDispositionFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5070 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5071 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5072 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5074 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5075 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5076 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5077 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5079 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5080 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5081 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5082 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5084 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.servlets.CoreFormHandlingServlet, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5085 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5086 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5087 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5089 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5090 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5091 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5093 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5095 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.distribution.servlet.DistributionAgentCreationFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   5295 LOG Applying Error filters
   5299 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
   5301 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
   5308 TIMER_START{handleError:status=404}
   5331 TIMER_END{21,handleError:status=404} Using handler /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp
   6214 LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html], order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobile: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, component-optional = true}}], values={jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured, component-optional=true}]), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobiledebug: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, component-optional = true}}], values={jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured, component-optional=true}]), Config(type=contentsync, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-contentsync: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, component-optional = true}}], values={jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured, component-optional=true}]), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
   7481 TIMER_END{7479,Request Processing} Dumping SlingRequestProgressTracker Entries
```

What's strange is that the template was removed long ago and there shouldn't be any reference to it. As a test I deleted the crx-quickstart folder and started from scratch. After doing a fresh install without any of my projects installed I still see that error. I thought maybe something was cached so I deleted my adobe folder in my cached folder (I'm on OS X). I tried moving the aem jars to a completely different location and I still had the same issue.

How could aem possibly know the name of an old project that was never installed? Is there somewhere where AEM caches these references?
How can I make it forget it and stop giving 404 errors?

Comment: But your current code seems to reference it. Did you checkout an old branch or did some colleges merge outdated code?

Comment: My current code or any other code was completely removed from the install. I deleted everything and made a fresh aem install. But even though it was completely blank and without any packages installed it somehow still knew about it. So basically, there is no current code.

Comment: Did you check the state of `/libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp`? This is the error page Sling tries to render and which references `/conf/MyOldProject/settings/wcm/templates/landing-page/structure/jcr:content/root/title.html`. I don't know about you module structure, hence I can't give a more qualified input.

Comment: I looked at the properties of that file, the folders above it, and the jcr:content item but there doesn't seem to be anything unusual in the properties section. I was looking at everything in crxde lite. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: What does the JSP try to do (rendering title.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure what it's trying to do. That's part of what I'm trying to figure out. I just get that 404 error when looking in the inspector when attempting to edit any template. Even if it's a brand new template with no components.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it was due to caching performed by chrome. As soon as I cleared on cached data related to my aem instance the error disappeared.